# Mysterious type of Omega

Tags: symbols, greek

I'm looking for this verion of Omega:

[image]

Comment: Try `\omega`...

Comment: Is not \omega ...

Comment: @AndreaLeo …and the font in your picture is not CM.

Comment: In what way is it "not \omega" apart from the fact it's a slightly odd font?

Comment: Sorry.. if I put  $ \omega $ latex produces a different type of Omega. I need this one in the picture :(

Comment: @AndreaLeo Can you add a minimal example of code that produces the “non omega”?

Comment: @AndreaLeo The font is probably Charter. With `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` you get the usual default math font for Charter, does that give you what you want? In any case, I would load `\usepackage{XCharter}` after that package to get a full featured text font. The text font is probably that, but no, the math font is not the one provided by `mathdesign`.

Comment: @Manuel unfortunally is not the Omega i want .. thank you

Comment: @AndreaLeo Look at The Font Catalogue for math fonts to see if one has *your* omega. (In any case, I suppose you do want the whole font, not only the omega, don't you?)

Comment: @AndreaLeo The symbol `\omega` is anything that the font designer chose to represent it. The actual shape is unimportant, so long as the letter is similar to its ancient representation in handwriting.

Comment: @AndreaLeo Perhaps you could explain why you need *this* particular omega.  Or are you writing a murder mystery or an episode of CSI in which the key to solving the murder hinges on identifying the particular font?

Comment: Make a good scan of the glyph, vectorize with Inkscape, save as pdf. Done, exactly the same omega.

Answer (score 2):

This might go in the right direction.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$I_{\mathrm{cm}} \omega^2$
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Well is very similar but is not that :(

Comment: @AndreaLeo You want the *same* font?

Comment: @Alenanno  Yes.. I need it :(

Comment: But, I don't understand you, why are you so certain you need that font, it's like requesting exactly this e - no other. It's still the same symbol, whichever font it is. There're just minor differences between fonts, which are up to the designer of the font. The only way to get *exactly* the same symbol is to use *exactly* the same font and it's almost impossible for us to know which font has been used - the font may not even be available to the general public, it may be the publisher's own in-house font. But it doesn't matter. ω is the same symbol as that, it doesn't need to be identical

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the artemisia option to the artemisia package?.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[artemisia]{textgreek}
\begin{document}
Omega: \textit{\textomega}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very very similar but it is still different